# I need to have more information (an image and description) about a site in Sharepoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a website in Sharepoint 2007 (it is a publishing portal).

I want to create a site with more specific info than what it comes with Sharepoint.
You know, when you create a new site, the only info you can enter is title and URL.

I would need an image and a description.

The solution is not a custom list, because i need to have pages inside and other lists.

How can i extend this site list?

Answer (score 2):

Write an application page or web part that creates the new site. Programmatically update it with what users enter in your custom form.

**Creating the site**

The [SPWebCollection.Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebcollection.add.aspx) method creates the site from a site definition. Create a custom definition that includes the site columns, content types and lists required. These will then be created as part of the site.

**Further customisations**

This won't perform all customisations however - for the rest develop a feature receiver. On activation it will run any arbitrary code on your new site.

For example as you are using a publishing site, retrieve its default page with the [DefaultPage property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishingweb.defaultpage.aspx). This is an SPFile object which has an [Item property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.item.aspx) that can be edited like any other SPListItem. Update the image field and description field for the item based on its content type. The page will then render these properties.

*All of the above can be wrapped in an [SPLongOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splongoperation.aspx) for a nicer user experience.*

There are other options as well, for example the [SPWebProvisioningProvider](http://blogs.technet.com/apurdon/archive/2008/02/05/the-mystery-that-is-spwebprovisioningprovider.aspx). The two separate steps above of creating a site definition and activating a feature receiver could be tied into one with this.

There is more information on the above techniques (plus others) and their pros and cons in [part 3](http://www.iwkid.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=55) and [part 4](http://www.iwkid.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=a9757dac-2555-45d8-a213-15c89d282620&ID=56) of this series by Raymond Mitchell.

Comment: +1 Excellent answer, Alex; you cover all the bases quite nicely!